# How to destructure an object that contains key names with hyphen?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to destructure this object:

```js
{
   name: "Bryan",
   last-name: "Enid"
}
```

and this is not possible:

```js
const {name, last-name} = req.body
```

Is there a way to destructure this, without changing the initial object key name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename the variable, because minus is an operator and not part of a variable name.

BTW, `name` is a property of [`Window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). if this is used you need to rename this value as well.

```js
const { name, 'last-name': lastName } = { name: 'foo', 'last-name': 'bar' };

console.log(lastName);
```

Comment: No need to use a computed property name though

Comment: @Bergi, right ...